# connecting to another network present in one network

Tags: networking, ip

I have been trying to create a server in one network but the people in another network cant connect to my server? Even though my IP is dynamic (dhcp :yes)

I want to create a server in one network but want to connect people to that  server present in another network. I started a server "eg: `103.251.9.85:27015`"
even though my IP is dynamic, they can't connect to my server? Help me ...

who ever knows my IP address and port number will connect to my server, but when I am starting a server they cant connect.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs a DNS record.

DHCP is great for allocating an IP address - but you then have to manually tell everyone what the IP Address is.

You should define your Server in your DHCP configuration, assuming that there is a DNS Server also.

By default the DHCPD informs the DNS Server - assuming they are both under your control.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that you have network connectivity between the nodes - there can be NATs, Firewalls and a lot of different reasons why you can not connect. My advice for you would be to try and use [netcat](http://sectools.org/tool/netcat/).

Once you have netcat on your computer - start it in a server mode. Then ask your friend to download netcat on his/her computer and connect to your IP address. If you can establish connection - great. Then make a question regarding your server program. If netcat fails - then there is network connectivity issue and you will find better help for those issues in the power user or network engineering Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: thank you for ur advice , i will try this netcat  software but this problem raised while am playing a LAN game (counter strike ). i started the server using hlds and informed  ip to my friend but we are not connected .